# Drupal RSS feed custom tag

Tags: theming, feeds

small question and I will keep it simple : I have a drupal website with an xml page. The xml is used by another website and needs a different '< TAG >'. The current tag for an image I'm using is '< enclosure url="url">< /enclosure>' and I need it to be '< image > URL HERE < /image >'.

Any tips or answers are welcome!

Comment: `The current tag for an image I'm using is '' and I need it to be ''` I suppose some text has gone missing?

Comment: @Neograph734 oh fixed it!

Comment: You should mentioned how your RSS feed is generated. Are you using the core feed (rss.xml)? Views?

Comment: Yes i do. @ShawnConn